# .NET Datagridview ComboBoxColumn -Selected Value

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have created an app in VB.NET containing a datagridview (dg), bound to a datatable.

I then create a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn and populate it with dropdown options from another datatable.

I bind it with the following:

```
        sHeader = "CType"
        With DDcol
            .DataSource = dtTemp
            .ValueMember = "VID"
            .DisplayMember = "Display"
            .HeaderText = sHeader
            .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
            .Name = sHeader
            .DisplayIndex = 1
        End With
```

dtTemp is a datatable containing values generated by SQL that looks like this if run in MS SQL Server Management Studio:

```
VID Display
1   Value One
2   Value Two
```

I then add the column to the datagridview.

```
dg.Columns.Add(DDcol)
```

It displays as expected.

However, the ValueMember doesn't take effect.

If I add an action to the dropdown column the value it produces is DBNULL. If I try to prepopulate the table in advance with code like the below, it doesn't work. Any help in solving this would be much appreciated.

```
dg.Rows(0).Cells(sHeader).Value = 1
```

Comment: Please, add all the relevant code; that is: what is `dtTemp`, how are you adding `DDcol` to the DGV, what is the value of `sHeader`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("vid", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("display", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "one" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "two" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "three" });
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn 
    { DataSource = dt, ValueMember = "vid", DisplayMember = "display" });
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = 1;
```

... and it worked perfectly ... maybe you can rewrite in vb.net yourself ...